# Why this Error: a value of type "const int*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*"?

Tags: visual-c++

This is my code:

```
int i = 5;
const int * cpi = &i; //pointer to const
int * pi = cpi; //Error: a value of type "const int*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is mutable, cause it is not a const type.
You try to store a int address in a const int address via `cpi`.

To solve it you have to actually hand over the values not the addresses.

Comment: Please suggest me any solution for error in the below piece of code.

class B{ 
public:
 B(){}
};
class A{
 B *b;
public:
 A(const B &bb) : b(&bb) {} //Getting Similar error here as well
};

Comment: I think this for the same reason as your original question.

C++ sees that the original variable `b` is not a const. You have to match the types in order to make this code running.
I think the solution would be to either remove the `const` in the constructor of `A` or defining `b` as a const as well.

I am not familiar with c++, maybe there is a casting convention where you can cast a const pointer to an mutable one